# Include Flow parameters in the failure email whenever a flow fails

Tags: python-3.x, ajax, email, scheduler, azkaban

I have a use case where I am using Azkaban Ajax calls to trigger a flow by providing flowOverride parameters. There will be multiple concurrent executions of this flow with around 100 different flow parameters.
Every time one of the execution fails, it becomes hard to identify what were the corresponding flow parameters of this failed execution.

Is there a way where we can include the flow parameters in the failure email itself?

I can see we can have onSuccess and onFailure emails that can be added. But nowhere in the azkaban documentation it refers how to alter he content of the failure email